# Find a string using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to extract "/html/path" from strings like these:

```
generic/html/path/generic/generic/generic
```

I just need "path" and it's always coming after "html/". So it there a way to search for "html/" and get the string after it until a "/" is coming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another one to add to the mix:

```
In [1]: s = 'generic/html/path/generic/generic/generic'

In [2]: s.split('html/')[1].split('/')[0]
Out[2]: 'path'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just basic string manipulation

```
s="generic/html/path/generic/generic/generic"
i1= s.index("html/") + 5
i2= s.index("/", i1)
print s[i1:i2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(".+html/(.+?)/")
>>> r = regex.search("generic/html/path/generic/generic/generic")
>>> r.groups()
(u'path',)
```

Python DOC: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html

Comment: That should be `".+html/(.+?)/"`, "get the string after it until a "/" is coming".

Comment: Oh he only wanted the `path` not the rest, thanks, updated the post.

Comment: I don't know much about beautifulsoup, but in the documentation there is sth. about regex: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression the example is only with finding tags, but if you can search in attributes (I think `href`) it should work the same way.